# Skepticism and alternative medicine

Tags: discussion

I don't know if there is a generally accepted answer to these questions, but I'd like to try anyway.

What is the definition of 'skepticism' in relation to  alternative medicine?

And a more specific question. Does skeptics have any positive claims about  alternative medicine? What would it take for a skeptic to accept  alternative medicine as a helpful way to treat illnesses and diseases?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics.SE](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) The main site is not for discussing skepticism itself, but for *applying* skepticism to claims, so I moved this to Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [acupuncture question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/402/is-acupuncture-an-effective-treatment) recently.  Some of the answers there may have "positive" aspects.

Answer (score 5):

Skepticism has many definitions. On this site, we apply "*scientific skepticism*". Wikipedia defines [scientific skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_skepticism).

> Scientific skepticism (also spelled scepticism) is the practice of questioning whether claims are supported by empirical research and have reproducibility, as part of a methodological norm pursuing "the extension of certified knowledge"

The article goes on to give more context. That's as good a definition as any. This is not related to alternative medicine - just a general definition of scientific skepticism.

> Does skeptics have any positive claims about alternative medicine?

It isn't clear what it means for skepticism to make positive claims. It is a process of questioning claims. Scientists may make positive claims.

> What would it take for a skeptic to accept alternative medicine as a helpful way to treat illnesses and diseases?

We have mechanisms for testing whether treatments are safe, effective, efficacious and cost-effective. Treatments that pass these tests are considered part of medicine.

Calling a treatment "alternative medicine" is often used as a technique to paint the treatment as medicine, when it hasn't passed the tests (or even has failed the tests.)

When an alternative medicine is accepted by science as a helpful treatment, it is no longer called alternative medicine. It is called medicine.

Comment: Just a suggestion, can we add information the need for randomized placebo controlled trials and meta-analysis to authenticate the efficacy of alternative medicine? Proponents always tend to vouch for the safety and cost effectiveness of herbs without referring to any authentic research!

Comment: @pericles316: In the first draft, I actually started to list some items (randomised controlled double-blind trials; tests for safety, effectiveness and efficacy; cost-effectiveness). I started talking about the difference between Science-Based and Evidence-Based Medicine. I was going to introduce the FDA and other governing bodies. Eventually, I realised I was writing the course-notes on a medical lecture I wasn't qualified to write, and kept it simple instead.